# Random error while creating storefront theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, fatal-error, command-line

Hi everyone I'm new to magento, few days ago I installed magento and now I was developing a sample storefront theme. But before i configure and install it, I just started facing an unknown error both on user end and admin side.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader' not found 
 in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php:215 Stack 
 trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php(116): 
 Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory- 
 >createDeploymentConfig(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList), 
 Object(Magento\Framework\Config\File\ConfigFilePool), Array) #1 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(211): 
 Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create(Array) #2 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(126): 
 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap- 
 >__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory), 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array) 
 #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(36): 
 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array) #4 {main} thrown in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory.php on line 215
```

When I try to run any command in magento directory it shows the following error in command-line:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\magento> php bin/magento cashe:flush
An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: 
Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig).
```

I try to reinstall magento by `composer update` but this also does not fix the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Later on I also deleted my new storefront theme directory but no joys.**

Comment: this being a `Filesystem\DirectoryList` I would assume a `Windows` issue, as Windows is not supported (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) maybe you could use an OS that is supported?

Comment: maybe but everything was working fine from about last 5 days. I also created some sample modules and successfully deployed them.

Comment: @Barry now i'm planing to create linux vm and install magento on it.

Comment: using a bitnami image is great for a quick test as its all pre installed

Comment: @Barry ok thanks